# How to get the column numbers that have a spesific class and use it to iterate through table

Tags: jquery

I have a table with headers in a `thead` section.

I need to add the class `colourme` to all the tables `td`s which have the table header class `selectme`. Only the first header has this class, so I somehow need to get the column numbers with a specific class and populate the rows columns with the same column number below it with the class `colourme`

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td, th {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
</style>
<body>
<table id="mytable" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Person</th>
        <th>Day 1</th>
        <th>Day 2</th>
        <th>Day 3</th>
        <th  class="selectme">Day 4</th>
        <th class="selectme">Day 5</th>
        <th>Day 6</th>
        <th>Day 7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Total:</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>4</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through `selectme` and select the body elements using `nth-child`

```js
$('#mytable thead .selectme').each(function(i) {
  $('#mytable tbody td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('colourme')
})
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.selectme,
.colourme {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3">Person</th>
      <th>Day 1</th>
      <th>Day 2</th>
      <th>Day 3</th>
      <th class="selectme">Day 4</th>
      <th class="selectme">Day 5</th>
      <th>Day 6</th>
      <th>Day 7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Total:</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```